# Merge Same Fields in Crystal Reports

Tags: merge, crystal-reports-2010

Is there a formula for this:

```
mainId docId groupId  code  product    price   qty      descrip         expDate  
123      1     1       6    pencil     20      1     long/yellow/hard   1/2/2014
123      2     2       8    book       10      1     thick/green        2/1/2014
123      3     3       6    pencil     20      1     long/yellow/hard   1/2/2014   
123      4     4       9    pencil     20      1     long/yellow/hard   1/2/2014
123      5     5       6    pencil     20      1     long/yellow/hard   1/2/2014
```

must merge if product, code, price, descrip, and expDate are all the same 
resulting to:

```
product: pencil       descrip: long/yellow/hard
                               1/2/2014 6
Computation: 20x1     20

product: pencil       descrip: long/yellow/hard
                               1/2/2014 9
Computation: 20x1     20

product: book         descrip: thick/green
                               2/1/2014 8
Computation: 10x1     10
```

Above the word (product, descrip, and Computation) are text label. Is there a way I can check the fields (product, code, price, descrip, and expDate) if they are the same or not.

**what I did is I put** 
groupbyproduct

```
Details area:
product(label)      computation(w/ code)     total(computation total - code)
```

end of groupbyproduct

Comment: use grouping on product

Comment: thanks Smita I'll try your suggestion

Comment: I already tried your suggestion but it still not working

Comment: What is the criteria to show details, what needs to be the same?